# Is my form not submitting by design or is there something else going on here?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am working in ASP.NET MVC and made a simple form that is AJAX enabled (using `MicrosoftAjax` and `MicrosoftMvcAjax`). All it does is pass the form value to a partial view, then updates the target element with the new value.

Here is the view with the form:

```
<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        <%=Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) ?? "Home Page"%></h2>
    <div>
        <p>
            <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxView", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Test" })) { %>
            <%= Html.Label("FormMessage","Message") %>
            <%= Html.TextBox("FormMessage")%>
            <br />
            <%= Html.Submit("Submit","Go") %>
            <% } %>
        </p>
        <p id="Test">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("AjaxView"); %>
        </p>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

here is the code from the controller:

```
public ActionResult AjaxView()
{
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        ViewData["AjaxMessage"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["FormMessage"]) ? "No Form Data!" : Request.Form["FormMessage"];
        return PartialView("AjaxView");
    }
    return View();
}
```

and here is the partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<%= ViewData["AjaxMessage"] ?? "Default Text" %>
```

Everything is working fine it seems, but when I try to enter something with `<` or `>`, the script does not execute. I am not intending for people to be able to enter html to this field, but why does the script fail to execute?

If it is a problem with the script getting confused by these characters, can I encode the incoming text (using `Server.HtmlEncode()` or something similar) before the ajax runs so that any 'unsafe' characters are converted and the script will continue on normally?

Thanks!

### edit

I just realized if I enter "<<", I will get "<" back from the script. Maybe this info will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebug's tab or Fiddler to look at the response from the server. It will probably tell you what the problem is. You should do this whenever an AJAX request is not behaving as you expect. With non-AJAX requests, the problem is usually obvious, because you see a yellow screen of death or something like that. With AJAX requests, you have to dig a little deeper to see the response, if it is not exactly what the calling JavaScript expects.

Chances are very good that the anti-XSS feature of ASP.NET is blocking anything with an angle bracket as potential HTML. If this is the problem, you will have a couple of choices. You can simply forbid angle brackets in a request (and presumably write some JavaScript to show a nicer message to the user) or you can encode them in JavaScript. Server.HtmlEncode won't help you, because you need to do this in JavaScript code, not C# code. Finally, you could turn off the anti-XSS feature by using the ValidateRequest(false) attribute on the action, in doing your own anti-XSS processing using something like the anti-XSS library on CodePlex.